# How to inject domain from environment variable into vuejs with require

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, webpack-file-loader

I have a special use case where I need the full url to an image to render on the html side. Ex; Facebook Open Graph requires the full image url to work properly, relative image or absolute path won't work.

I'm currently working in with @vue/cli and typescript. I have the following component:

`example.vue`

```vue
<template>
  <div id="example">
    <img :src="exampleIcon" alt="Example"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        exampleIcon: require(`../assets/exampleIcon.png`),
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

The above renders fine, it produces an img tag that results in this:

```html
<img src="/img/exampleIcon.8d0b1a90.png" alt="Example">
```

but let's say my domain is `example.com`, here's what I would like to have as a result instead:

```html
<img src="https://example.com/img/exampleIcon.8d0b1a90.png" alt="Example">
```

I don't want to hardcode anything in the template. I would like to use an environment variable so I can inject the domain when building the vue bundle:

```typescript
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
      };
    },
  };
```

Some related documentation:

- [vue-loader asset-url](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html)
- [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/)

Comment: After searching a little more, I found the following issue: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/290 and the proposed solution seems right. I'll give this a try and will update here.

Comment: Ok I can confirm that doing something like ```'http://localhost:8081' + require(`../assets/large_image.png`)``` does work, but I just found that smaller images are being converted to base64 encoded inline images so this can cause other problems.

Comment: The following solution also works and doesn't require an environment variable: `let url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;` followed by ```url + require(`../assets/large_image.png`)```. source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If it did, please accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I went with [my comment here instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490871/how-to-inject-domain-from-environment-variable-into-vuejs-with-require?noredirect=1#comment91922613_52490871) and used `window.location.host`. I did not want to hardcode domains, I only wanted the full url as it's a tool anyone could run from anywhere and there is no predefined production url. Not quite sure why, but the node process didn't grab my `process.env.BASE_URL`, I did not dig further but I'm ok using `window.location.host`.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close.

Instead of getting a value of `baseUrl` from an environmental variable, set the value based on the environment you build the current app for:

```
data() {
  return {
    baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'? "https://example.com" : 'http://localhost:8081'
  }
```

I guess you have different npm scripts for `production` environment and `development` environment. In webpack 4 you can use use [mode](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/).

[Read more about environments](https://simonsmith.io/organising-webpack-config-environments/).